# Connecting to remote neo4j using Java API

Tags: neo4j

I'm writing a test app that makes use of neo4j. I've been trying to follow a few tutorials, reading online, and also checking the documentation, and the most common way of making use of the Java API made available is to use an embedded neo4j.

Now, for multiple reasons this will not work for me. (Eg. server on different machine, etc.)

I'm using :

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "2.1.5",
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-rest-graphdb" % "2.0.1",
```

And connecting to neo4j this way :

```
GraphDatabaseService gds = new RestGraphDatabase("http://neo4jserver_address:7474/db/data");
```

As anwsered before on another SO post, the `RestGraphDatabase` is not a complete implementation of `GraphDatabaseService` , which leads to all sorts of trouble when trying to use , for example, other libs such as :

```
"com.graphaware.neo4j" % "timetree" % "2.1.5.25.18",
```

Also, the fact that `RestGraphDatabase` doesn't allow usage of `GlobalGraphOperations` because of that same problem.

I've tried seaching the official documentation I've found and again, the examples given are for embedded DB.

My question is if anyone knows of the correct way to connect to a remote neo4j server the right way and where in the documentation I can read about this bit?

Also, no I'm not using neo4j HA , although I have a 1 year testing license.

PS - connection over REST is not required. Protocol is irrelevant, what the question is is how to connect to a remote neo4j server (over whatever protocol) using the API and ending up with a proper, full implementation of `GraphDatabaseService`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that what you really want is a `GraphDatabaseService` object that's attached to a RESTful endpoint.  That's what your code says, but based on my best understanding of the situatioin, you also have the facts right about problems and limitations with that implementation.

OK, so given that - I think your best answer is to [use the REST API directly from java](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html).   That link provides detailed documentation.  But essentially, you won't be dealing with `Node` and `Relationship` objects, but rather you'll be working with HTTP requests and responses, and JSON processing.

See the examples behind the link I provided, it provides lots of code examples for how to get this to work.  The good news is that you can do anything on the server side.  The bad news is that it's way less convenient.   I'm hoping too for a really good `GraphDatabaseService` implementation in the future.   It would be very powerful if my code didn't have to care whether the DB was a local file, or a remote service.

Comment: This would mean I need to rewrite all the code I already have that is working. 

I don't mind not connecting through the REST endpoint, if there is anywhere else I can connect to, using any other thing. It is of core importance that I get a `GraphDatabaseService` to a remote server, be it REST, some other TCP protocol (that actually allows transactions) , or whatever. 

Is there no other way?

Comment: I do not know of another way in pure java.  Hopefully someone will come along and prove me wrong, because personally I would like to have what you're asking for myself.  But here's another out of the box idea:  py2neo has a wrapper that does most of you want, but it's  python.  Perhaps you could write jython code against py2neo?  Wouldn't be java, but would run on the JVM.  http://py2neo.org/2.0/

Comment: It just seem really strange that there would be no implementation of Java API to allow connection to remote server. Like... everyone is using embedded DB with java? I don't get it. Lets give this thread a bit more time and see if anyone comes along and help us out. Thanks for you feedback and ideas

Comment: Fair enough, absolutely give the thread more time.  I'm also going to post something on twitter to see if I can attract some other neo4j people.  Like I said, I'm hoping I'm wrong and there's a better answer.

Comment: There's also this option, but it's not going to let you keep your existing code (see 27.2):  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/reference_neo4j-server.html

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to code on the native Java API and use a remote server, Neo4j unmanaged server extensions gives you exactly that. You can write your code on top of the Java API but deploy that on a remote server. We support that in GrapheneDB and it's the best approach to implement complex algorithms or achieve higher performance. I hope you found this helpful. You can read about unmanaged extensions at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Comment: @albertoperdomo correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought unmanaged server extensions were for adding new behaviors to the server, and possibly exposing those as RESTful services.  Sounds like OP might not want anything different, he just wants the GraphDatabaseService API but over REST.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits over Rest or over whatever, underlying implementation is irrelevant as long as it is remote and full `GraphDatabaseService` implementation is available.

Comment: @albertoperdomo Unmanaged server extensions sounds alright (I can copy and past the existing code which is fine) , the problem is : coupling my business logic with the data layer doesn't sound right. I might be seeing it the wrong way around, but I don't want to extend functionality to the DB , I want to access data and modify it remotely using transactions, and leave the DB alone. The paradigm might be different when using graph dbs, I don't know, but it really doesn't sound right to be writing extensions when what I require is transaction support for multiple operations on a remote server.

Comment: I think you should think about it slightly differently. Either you want to use Neo4j as a remote database. In this case, you send queries (Cypher) over REST and get results as (potentially streamed) responses. Or you choose to use the imperative API, where you want to physically traverse the graph step by step. This would be very inefficient over the network, even if a proper REST wrapper around GraphDatabaseService existed. An extension in this case makes sense. The "heavy-lifting" code is where your data is, and a REST API gets exposed to the client - a common (and IMHO encouraged) pattern.

Comment: @MichalBachman I believe we are missing the point here. There is no heavy lifting to be made. What I'm talking about is the need to use transactions in my business logic (and therefore an API that supports that, with a remote database). Business logic which I want to reside in my App Server, and not in the DB layer. That is it. For example, at this moment, as it is I can't use "your" `timetree` lib remotely. Business logic on the app server, layer separation and all the benefits that come with it.

Comment: @SysHex I'm becoming increasingly confident of my original answer, a full GDS implementation doesn't exist.  You say in the question protocol doesn't matter, but it does; REST is the way you connect to a remote neo4j database. It seems what you're looking for is like an equivalent of JDBC for neo4j (i.e. a connection protocol that works the same both local and remote).  Such a thing doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Just got back an email with that response and also that work on a the binary protocol way of connecting to neo4j is about to start. Maybe then a GDS implementation will appear. Also, from another SO post (forgot the link), got a reference to OrientDB , which looks really good.

Comment: I understand. If there's no heavylifting then extensions don't make much sense for you probably, since you are wanted to avoid the coupling of code with your data layer. Since GDS is not available over REST then you would usually rely on Cypher + transaction endpoint to connect your app to the remote Neo4j instance. This is more or less what others have pointed out too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this could be of your help;

```
RestAPI restapi = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
RestCypherQueryEngine rcqer=new RestCypherQueryEngine(restapi)
```

this allows you to use the actual cypher query which you execute in neo4j shell;

```
String query = "Start n=node(*) return count(n) as totalRecords"
    QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> queryResult = rcqer.query(query,org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map("null",null))
    for(Map<String,Object> row:queryResult){
        numberOfNodes = row.get("totalRecords")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [JCypher](https://github.com/Wolfgang-Schuetzelhofer/jcypher) provides what you need:

> JCypher provides database access in a uniform way to remote as well as
>   to embedded databases (including in-memory databases)